# Ember Simple Auth - authorizationFailed not executing session invalidation or transitionTo

Tags: session, ember.js, authorization, ember-simple-auth

Problem: Unauthorized requests do not invalidate session and transition to root url. The default method isn't working so I'm overriding it.

My Custom Authorizer

```
var CustomAuthorizer = Base.extend({
 authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('session.token'))) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('ApiKey', this.get('session.token'));
    }
 }
});
```

authorizationFailed hook

```
authorizationFailed: function(session){
  console.log('authorizationFailed'); //displays in console
  this.get('session').invalidate('authenticator:custom', {}); //doesn't invalidate
  console.log(this.get('session')); //still return authenticated session
  this.transitionTo('index'); //doesn't transition
}
```

I know that the problem is because the invalidation is asynchronous so the promise for the invalidation doesn't return in time for the console.log to spit out the invalidated session. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `Session#invalidate` does expect any arguments according to the [API docs](http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Session-invalidate).

Comment: Tried `this.get('session').invalidate();` but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate` returns a promise, you should wait for that promise to be fullfiled before transitioning.

```
this.get('session').invalidate('authenticator:custom', {}).then(function() {
  this.transitionTo('index');
});
```

Comment: I've also tried that too and it doesn't work. I logged out the session after the `then` but it still returns the authenticated session